# calling a phalcon php MVC controller via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, model-view-controller, phalcon

i am using simple app with phalcon PHP and AngularJs. i am trying to call my phalcon PHP controller from angularJS controller through AJAX POST request.

```
 $http.post('/ControllerName/', {params});
```

and i get

> 404 The requested URL /ControllerName/ was not found on this server

i think my request is being routed to my public folder whereas my php controller is located in Non-public folder.

these are the .htaccess rules i have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]</IfModule>
```

and in the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]</IfModule>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, My problem was in the rewrite mechanism as i thought.
First, in httpd.conf file i had to:

1. Change "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" in the relevant directory.
2. My "mod_rewrite" was disabled, so i had to un-comment the line: "#
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption you are using a default and working deployment of phalcon I suggest you to check for trailing slashes, there is a manual voice about that: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html anchor **#dealing-with-extra-trailing-slashes**

you can also test your routes with a custom script: same url before, anchor **#testing-your-routes**

... or.. you can put your nose into the routing system to try to find where the failure is by listening on dispatcher for **dispatch:beforeDispatchLoop**, there is a piece of code here http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#inject-model-instances, you can see in the event function how the framework would guess the controller and action names:

```
//Possible controller class name
$controllerName = Text::camelize($dispatcher->getControllerName()) . 'Controller';

//Possible method name
$actionName = $dispatcher->getActionName() . 'Action';
```

... they should then exists for a successful routing, btw refer to the example code